# Visual Studio SDK - Handle mouse events for margins

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

Is there any way to override mouse events connected with the Visual Studio IDE margin? I looked at the [IMouseProcessorProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.imouseprocessorprovider.aspx) interface, but it seems to work only with mouse events connected with the code editor window. For example:

```
public override void PostprocessMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MyMethod();
}
```

MyMethod gets called only when I click the left button somewhere in the code editor window. I would like it to be called after clicking on a margin. How can I implement that?

Comment: This is possible in theory, since Visual Studio is mostly WPF based. All you need to do is to get ahold of the WPF visual element (`UIElement`) for the margin, and then you can attach event listeners to the PreviewMouse* events.

Comment: Thank you @Cameron. Thanks to you I found a solution - I was able to get the UIElement object of my custom glyph and then handle the mouse event I was interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution - I was interested in calling MyMethod after clicking on my custom glyph on the margin, so I fetched the UIElement object representing the glyph (from my glyph factory class) and then I was able to implement MouseLeftButtonDown event.

Comment: I found another solution - using [IGlyphMouseProcessorProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iglyphmouseprocessorprovider.aspx)